# InstalledVoices.All returns voices that are not installed

Tags: windows-phone-8, text-to-speech

I have a problem trying to use text to speech synthesis in Mexican Spanish. I first check that the Spanish Voice is installed:

```
String Text = "some text in Spanish";

IEnumerable<VoiceInformation> spanishVoices = from voice in InstalledVoices.All
    where voice.Language == "es-MX"
    select voice;

if (spanishVoices.ElementAt(0) != null)
    synth.SetVoice(spanishVoices.ElementAt(0));

await synth.SpeakTextAsync(Text);
```

Now, the debugger shows that `spanishVoices.ElementAt(0)` is not null, but I get a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`, which doesn't happen if I comment out the `if` block (and I get the text pronounced as if it was written in English).

After checking the speech settings on the phone, it turns out that the the phone needs to download the Spanish voices. After doing that, the app works as intended.

So, the problem is that `InstalledVoices.All` is not telling the truth, as Spanish is not really installed.

Is there any reliable way to make sure that it really is?

Comment: I suspect that exception is as good as it is going to get.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour with `SpeechSynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices()`?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on WP since 7.5, and it's always been a frustrating and buggy platform.

The only way I can think of to list the voices that are *really* there:

```cs
var voices = new List<VoiceInformation>();
using (var s = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    foreach (var v in InstalledVoices.All)
    {
        try
        {
            s.SetVoice(v);
            s.SpeakTextAsync(" ").AsTask().Wait();
            voices.Add(v);
        } catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Note that setting the voice wouldn't fail, one needs to run the TTS for it to fail... It looks like the platform *thinks* that the voice is there, but the file with the 'voice bank' is not.

Note also, that it would take a few seconds for this code to run, because of the exceptions being thrown (originating from COM), meaning it is not a good idea to put this code in a static initializer.